# Grouping pairs in array of lists

Tags: python, list, match

I've ran a multi-spearman correlation across different paired variables and found these columns to be most correlated. I would like to find groups of pairs within these correlations `e.g. [col_147,col_141,col_319]` which **may be** be all paired to each other.

```
array([list(['col_165', 'col_184']), list(['col_147', 'col_319']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_319']), list(['col_142', 'col_148']),
       list(['col_312', 'col_316']), list(['col_141', 'col_316']),
       list(['col_147', 'col_316']), list(['col_316', 'col_319']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_312']), list(['col_147', 'col_312']),
       list(['col_312', 'col_319']), list(['col_314', 'col_318']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_142']), list(['col_142', 'col_147']),
       list(['col_147', 'col_148']), list(['col_141', 'col_148']),
       list(['col_142', 'col_319']), list(['col_311', 'col_317']),
       list(['col_148', 'col_319']), list(['col_142', 'col_316']),
       list(['col_148', 'col_316']), list(['col_142', 'col_312']),
       list(['col_148', 'col_312']), list(['col_313', 'col_317']),
       list(['col_313', 'col_315']), list(['col_149', 'col_316']),
       list(['col_149', 'col_312']), list(['col_143', 'col_147']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_143']), list(['col_143', 'col_319']),
       list(['col_143', 'col_148']), list(['col_23', 'col_25']),
       list(['col_149', 'col_319']), list(['col_141', 'col_149']),
       list(['col_147', 'col_149']), list(['col_311', 'col_313']),
       list(['col_143', 'col_315']), list(['col_149', 'col_311']),
       list(['col_142', 'col_149']), list(['col_142', 'col_143']),
       list(['col_143', 'col_316']), list(['col_143', 'col_312']),
       list(['col_143', 'col_317']), list(['col_148', 'col_149']),
       list(['col_315', 'col_317']), list(['col_149', 'col_313']),
       list(['col_151', 'col_48']), list(['col_145', 'col_151']),
       list(['col_145', 'col_170']), list(['col_170', 'col_48']),
       list(['col_145', 'col_189']), list(['col_189', 'col_48']),
       list(['col_148', 'col_318']), list(['col_145', 'col_18']),
       list(['col_18', 'col_48']), list(['col_142', 'col_318']),
       list(['col_188', 'col_312']), list(['col_187', 'col_312']),
       list(['col_169', 'col_312']), list(['col_168', 'col_312']),
       list(['col_170', 'col_245']), list(['col_189', 'col_245']),
       list(['col_151', 'col_245']), list(['col_143', 'col_313']),
       list(['col_149', 'col_317']), list(['col_188', 'col_316']),
       list(['col_187', 'col_316']), list(['col_169', 'col_316']),
       list(['col_168', 'col_316']), list(['col_145', 'col_245']),
       list(['col_245', 'col_48']), list(['col_184', 'col_76']),
       list(['col_184', 'col_75']), list(['col_165', 'col_76']),
       list(['col_165', 'col_75']), list(['col_187', 'col_314']),
       list(['col_188', 'col_314']), list(['col_169', 'col_314']),
       list(['col_168', 'col_314']), list(['col_148', 'col_314']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_188']), list(['col_141', 'col_187']),
       list(['col_147', 'col_188']), list(['col_147', 'col_187']),
       list(['col_141', 'col_169']), list(['col_141', 'col_168']),
       list(['col_147', 'col_169']), list(['col_147', 'col_168'])],
      dtype=object)
```

First thought was to find unique values, loop these through the pairs until you find a match, and then look through the matched unique values until you find matches with those, and so on. But I'm sure there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not sure if I understood you correctly.

In your example `[col_147,col_141,col_319]` should be paired, but I could not find a direct connection between `col_147` and `col_141`

So if a shared connection to `col_319` is already enough for grouping, the following code is wrong.

If on the other hand you are looking for groups, where each item has direct connection to each other item, well - here you are:

```
from collections import defaultdict

connections = defaultdict(set)
for pair in array:
    connections[pair[0]].update(pair)
    connections[pair[1]].update(pair)

groups = set()
for others in connections.values():
    relations = [others] + [connections[o] for o in others]
    intersection = set.intersection(*relations)
    if len(intersection) > 2:
        groups.add(frozenset(intersection))

for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
frozenset({'col_312', 'col_142', 'col_319', 'col_148', 'col_316'})
frozenset({'col_76', 'col_184', 'col_165'})
frozenset({'col_312', 'col_316', 'col_141'})
frozenset({'col_149', 'col_317', 'col_311', 'col_313'})
frozenset({'col_165', 'col_75', 'col_184'})
frozenset({'col_315', 'col_313', 'col_317', 'col_143'})
frozenset({'col_312', 'col_147', 'col_316'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_groups(pairs):
    groups_list = list()
    for pair in pairs:
        s = ab = set(pair)
        for t in groups_list[:]: # we need to use copy
            if t & ab:           # check t include a, b
                s |= t
                groups_list.remove(t)
        groups_list.append(s)    # only s include a, b
    return groups_list

find_groups(pairs)
```